# Parent menu able to add active class but submenu unable to add selected class

Tags: html, css

```js
 $(".sidebar_nav-main li").on("click", function() {
        $(".sidebar_nav-main li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
    
      $(".sidebar-subchild-collapse li").on("click", function() {
        $(".sidebar-subchild li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
      });
```

```css
.active {
  box-shadow: rgb(237, 156, 40) 4px 0px 0px inset;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);

}

.selected{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.05);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href="Sidebar.css">
  </head>
<body>
    <div class="sidebar-left" id="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-header">
          <div class="sidebar-title">Sidebar</div>
          <div class="sidebar-collapse" id="sidebar-collapse">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" ></i>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar-content">
              <nav class="sidebar_nav" role="navigation">
                  <ul id=sidebar-accordion class="sidebar_nav-main">
                      <li class="sidebar-link dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu" aria-expanded="false">
                          <a href="#" class="sidebar_main-link">
                              <span class="sidebar-item">Menu</span>
                          </a>
                          <div class="sidebar-subchild-hover">
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu sidebar_submenu">
                                  <li class="dropdown-item sidebar_submenu-item"><a href="#"><span>Menu 1</span></a></li>
                                  <li class="dropdown-item sidebar_submenu-item"><a href="#"><span>Menu 2</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                          <div class="sidebar-subchild-collapse" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
                            <ul data-parent="#sidebar-accordion" id="sidebar_submenu" class="collapse sidebar_submenu">
                              <li class="gdc-sidebar_submenu-item selected"><a href="#"><span>Menu 1</span></a></li>
                              <li class="gdc-sidebar_submenu-item"><a href="#"><span>Menu 2</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <script src="./Sidebar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Good Day and very much need help! I am doing the sidebar menu. The problem I facing now is when the active class for my parent menu is able to run. Switching between multiple parent menus will show the correctly active class. But when using the same script on the submenu, it was not able to switch between multiple submenus. The selected class keeps staying at the first submenu item and will not change. I am still thinking about how could this happen. If anyone can help then it was so much appreciated!!

Comment: it is because you've used event.stopPropogation() onClick of sidebar-subchild-collapse

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I was used the stop propogation to prevent the submenu auto close once clicked it.